# How can I solve problem about "True" or "False" about python turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I heard that `tx==comx` and `ty==comy` doesn't make `True` or `False` data.

How can I solve this problem ?

```
a=0

tx=t1.xcor()
ty=t1.ycor()
comx=turtles[i].xcor()
comy=turtles[i].ycor()

if tx==comx and ty==comy:
    a=1
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what you heard. The test `tx==comx and ty==comy` will produce either `True` or `False` (but not `'True'` nor `'False'` because those are both strings not boolean values).

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood something. Your code seems fine, at least the last part where you check your `tx` and `ty` content. If both return `True`, a will become one.

Comment: why do you check x and y separately and not use [`turtle.position()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.position) which will return tuple `(x, y)`?

Answer (score 0):

`xcor()` and `ycor()` will both return a floating point value (that is a number with decimals).

If these coordinates (x and y) are the same for `tx` and `comx` as well as for `ty` and `comy`, then a=1 will be processed. The only problem I see is that it can be a tripping stone to compare two decimal numbers for equality (1.0000001 ≠ 1.0).

But basically your if-statement should work. Try:

```
a = 3
b = 2
if a==3 and b==2:
    print("I happen!")
```

Comment: I understand what you said. But I want to know how to finish the turtle program.
I put the code["turtle.bye(),wn.bye()"] at 'front of mainloop() or front of listen() but I can't finish my program.

Comment: temp=t1.distance(turtles[i])

        if temp==0:            
            a=1

    if a==1:
        turtle.bye()
        wn.bye()


    
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()

Comment: That is a completely different question to which we can only answer if we get a well structured piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Back away from the approach you're attempting.  Turtles wander a floating point plane and can be right on top of each other but still not at the exact same coordinates.  There's a turtle method to deal with this called `distance()`:

```
a = 0

if t1.distance(turtles[i]) <= 1:
    a = 1
```

Comment: I understand what you said. But I want to know how to finish the turtle program. I put the code at 'front of mainloop() or front of listen() but I can't finish my program.  I understand what you said. But I want to know how to finish the turtle program.
I put the code["turtle.bye(),wn.bye()"] at 'front of mainloop() or front of listen() but I can't finish my program.

Comment: temp=t1.distance(turtles[i])

        if temp==0:            
            a=1

    if a==1:
        turtle.bye()
        wn.bye()


    
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()

Comment: @안수한, what can I say?  You completely miss the point of my answer when you do the exact comparison `if temp==0:` -- consider instead `if temp < 1:`